# assert_difference with a String?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

Here's a standard `insert_difference` update test:

```
assert_difference 'Article.count' do
  post :create, article: {...}
end
```

Is it possible to do something equivalent to `insert_difference` when a String is being tested?

```
assert_difference 'Article.name' do
  post :create, article: {...}
end
# TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String
```

Comment: What are you trying to assert here? `assert_difference` is meant to test that a number was adjusted by a certain amount. What sort of data does `Article.name` return?

Comment: Hi @tadman - `Article.name` returns a String. I want to check whether it has changed as a result of the operation.

Comment: Of course, I can test this in a more 'clunky' way but I'm wondering if there's a nice way to do it, and why assert_difference doesn't apply to any variable type!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The low-tech way of doing this:

```
assert_equal 'before', Article.name

post :create, article: { ... }

assert_equal 'after', Article.name
```

If you want you can write your own assert method to wrap that up, but unless this is used pervasively in your tests I'd avoid doing that, it confuses what's actually going on.

`assert_difference` is intended to be used on methods that return integer values, nothing more, but you could use that design as a basis for your own string-based one.

Now what I'm finding odd here is that `Article.name` is a class method, so if you're expecting a particular instance to change, you'll need to do it this way:

```
article = articles(:example)

assert_equal 'before', article.name

post :create, article: { ... }

article.reload

assert_equal 'after', article.name
```

That's what I tend to see in a lot of tests trying to assert a record was actually changed.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. I wonder why the Rails team don't make `assert_difference` work for non-integer cases - it seems logical that it should.

Comment: What does "difference" mean with a string? In the integer case the delta parameter is quite clear.

Comment: Well, 'difference' to me means the String has changed. i.e. anything where `string1 != string2`.

Comment: The `assert_difference` method asserts a numerical difference, by default +1. You can tell it other values, like 0, -10, or 10. Maybe you want to write `assert_changed`. Consider that something having changed is pretty meaningless, it might've been deleted. It's always best to check that it was changed to an expected value.